# How to programatically add folder to Spotlight "do not index"?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, command-line, spotlight

Is there any way to programmatically add a folder to Spotlight's "Privacy" tab?
Either through Terminal or Applescript?

Often I want to click on an item in Spotlight results in Finder, and have that item's folder no longer be indexed.

I found that if you

```
sudo defaults read /Volumes/foo/.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist Exclusions
```

you can see an array with all the items excluded.

But if you try to

```
sudo defaults write  /Volumes/foo/.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist Exclusions -array-add '/path/to/folder'
```

it does NOT get added to the Privacy tab in the Spotlight Preference Panel, nor does it get de-indexed.

Answer (score 26):

According to an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/591406/how-do-i-disable-indexing-in-a-specific-directory-across-multiple-platforms), a folder can be excluded from Spotlight indexing (achieving the same effect as adding it to the Privacy tab, although the folder won't actually be listed there) by either

- adding `.noindex` to the end of the folder's name, or
- creating an empty file `.metadata_never_index` inside the folder (eg with `touch folder/.metadata_never_index`)

You will need to restart Finder after adding  `.metadata_never_index`, either `killall Finder` from Terminal or logout from the Apple menu and then log back in. This method doesn't work in Mojave and later.

Comment: @ankii You've added "This method doesn't work in Mojave and later". Does that apply to the entire answer, or just the final paragraph?

Comment: Just the .meta_never_index method. See some discussion here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375396/spotlight-ignores-metadata-never-index?noredirect=1&lq=1 I am doubtful of High Sierra, but Mojave is surely ignorant of the same. If you want to edit it, put a space before *You will need..* and it will fix the ambiguity of which method it applies to.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully these comments document it well enough.

Comment: If the `.metadata_never_index` doesn't work on Mojave, then how can we disable indexing on a whole volume? (not just a single dir)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I think that's worthy of an entirely new question - this question is about folders, and my guess is that changing this at the volume level would need quite different solutions.

Comment: @Ashley I asked here because for a mounted volume, it used to be the case that just creating the `.metadata_never_index` at the root was enough, it behaves like a folder. I don’t know what to do now :-/

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Sorry for delay - I forgot about this. I'd suggest asking a new question, with details of your system, what you've tried, what you are seeing and what you expected instead. Then put another comment here with a link to it, and I'll try and help (although can't promise anything).

Comment: Or see Cameron Lowell Palmer's new answer

Answer (score 11):

### The `VolumeConfiguration.plist` has moved

It now resides in `/System/Volumes/Data/.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist`.

You can easily edit it using `/uar/libexec/PlistBuddy`

#### Reading

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :Exclusions" /System/Volumes/Data/.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist
```

#### Writing

The zero indicates the element in the array or in this case the beginning of the array

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :Exclusions:0 string '/path/to/folder'" /System/Volumes/Data/.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist
```

#### Deleting

The zero indicates the the first item in the array

```
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :Exclusions:0 string" /System/Volumes/Data/.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist
```

#### Restart the daemon

Easiest solution to get the change to take effect is reboot, but you can also tell `Launchd` to restart the mdworkers

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.metadata.mds
sudo launchctl start com.apple.metadata.mds
```

#### mdutil

If however, you decide you want to disable spotlight indexing on the whole volume, for example if the machine is a headless build machine, you could just use `mdutil`.

```
mdutil -i off /
```

Comment: While the _commands_ you posted do as stated, they do not change the current state of **Spotlight** _indexing_, nor does the added entries show in **System Preferences** > **Spotlight** > **Privacy**. So unless you have a way to also make the changes go into effect, then  not sure of the value of this answer.

Comment: You'll need to restart of course or restart the daemon

Comment: If you have an error running these commands (e.g., `Error Reading File: ...`), you probably need to give your terminal program full-disk access (under `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access`).

Comment: @user3439894 if you want your changes to appear under Spotlight > Privacy, you will need to do so manually. Maybe there is an MDM way? However, the goal here is to disable searching for a given directory, so in that I believe this works.

Answer (score 6):

You have to stop and start the `launchd` service called `com.apple.metadata.mds`. So after:

```
sudo defaults write /Volumes/foo/.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist Exclusions -array-add '/path/to/folder'
```

do:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.metadata.mds && sudo launchctl start com.apple.metadata.mds
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the permission settings to add something to the spotlight privacy tab
`sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP /.Spotlight-V100/`
 `sudo chmod -R 777 /.Spotlight-V100/`

and then

`sudo defaults write /.Spotlight-V100/Store-V1/Exclusions Exclusions -array-add`
should work.

And don't forget to set it back afterwards.

Comment: When I did `-array-add` the folder was added to the plist; it just didn't have any effect. In other words, it showed up with `defaults read`, but it did NOT show up in the Pref Panel. Do you think this permission mod would make a difference?

Comment: I am not so sure, but the defaults are -rwx-------?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I thought it would not get added at all. I am not so sure, but the defaults are -rwx-------? In this case you may be right and it should not make any difference if you have it changed -rwxrwxrwx with chmod 777. But it is worth a try!?

Comment: I believe Store-V1 is only used by older versions of Mac OS X... it is empty on my systems with 10.9 Mavericks and later. You might try modifying the command to use Store-V2 instead.

Comment: For me it just says operation not permitted. I'm on mojave.

Answer (score -5):

You could also just go to the system prefs pane for Spotlight. There you'll find a privacy tab. Just add the folders and files you don't want to show up in the index. That's it. They've already made it easy so you don't have to use the command line.

And If it's added to the privacy tab you can see what all you have hidden from the index just in case you want to index it it later.

Comment: The question was about how to do this programmatically. Obviously it can be done via GUI.

Comment: @Ze'ev: A valid point... but next time, since doing it programmatically is so central to the question, you should probably include "programmatically" in the title.

Comment: @Ze'ev: your question details disagree with your title. You need to make your title clear and accurate to the question