# Prevent spotlight from indexing folders with a certain name

Tags: spotlight, indexing

Is there a way to globally ignore folders with a certain name (say `node_modules`)

I know I can do it manually for each instance but I was wondering if its possible to just let spotlight know not to index these folders? `node_modules`, for example, typically has thousands of files that I don't want to search and it ends up slowing down spotlight.

I've looked around but I can only find answers that suggest manually adding folders in spotlight privacy list. Does someone have a better, glob way to it?

Comment: Adding specific folders to the Spotlight privacy is the way to have it ignore during indexing.  Why are you against doing it the Apple-provided way?

Comment: Because I want to ignore many instances of this folder and doing that "the apple-provided way" will be time-consuming and ineffective (I might miss some). In addition to that, whenever a new `node_modules` folder is created, I'll have to go and add it manually.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87090/how-to-programatically-add-folder-to-spotlight-do-not-index

Comment: Everyone facing this issue, please submit a request to https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html so they'll do something about it!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no known method to exclude from Spotlight a file or a folder based on a pattern (ex.: its name).

However it's possible to exclude a folder from Spotlight by adding to it an empty file `.metadata_never_index`.

You can use this method to ignore all `node_module`and `bower_modules` folders:

```sh
find /path/to/projects -type d  -path '*node_modules/*' -prune -o -type d -name 'node_modules' -exec touch '{}/.metadata_never_index' \;
```

---

Edit:

It look like the method `.metadata_never_index` is ignored by Spotlight since Mojave.

---

Edit 2:

As @JohnLee pointed it out, the extended attribute [`com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem`](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/12/13/xattr-com-apple-metadatacom_apple_backup_excludeitem-exclude-from-backups/) is not related / doesn't have any impact on Spotlight.

However `*.noindex` and symlink aren't indexed by mds (the backend of Spotlight). You can use it as band-aid:

```sh
# Rename all node_modules to node_modules.noindex and create a symlink node_modules -> node_modules.noindex
find /path/to/projects -type d \( -path '*node_modules/*' -o -path '*node_module.noindex/*' \) -prune -o -type d -name 'node_modules' -exec mv '{}' '{}.noindex' \; -exec ls -s '{}.noindex' '{}' \;
```

Note: if you use [npm-ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci), the `node_modules` is "automatically removed before npm ci begins its install".

Comment: I cannot confirm that this works for my Mac with Sierra as of today. I ran the script and can find all the hidden `.metadata_never_index` files in my node_modules, yet after a forced refresh of the spotlight index, the files are still being indexed. There is also a node_modules NPM Github PR open but I am afraid that this won't be the final solution to the problem https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15346

Comment: Note: Chrome and Opera use it for profile folder. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395300#c5

Comment: Sadly `.metadata_never_index` is not honored on mojave.

Comment: @mems the linked article talks about it being excluded from backups, but doesn't talk about Spotlight. Do you have a source that talks about it in relation to Spotlight?

Comment: @JohnLee you right, it's an attribute used by TimeMachine to exlude files, not Spotlight

Answer (score 15):

In case anyone missed [fsb](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/88313/fsb)'s comment in the question, *as I did*. Apple provides a privacy tab in the Spotlight settings.

Goto "System Preferences" > "Spotlight" > "Privacy" > "+" Add folders to the list.

Note: This may not work immediately, I had to restart Spotlight to see the effects.

Comment: Hi I wonder how to restart spotlight?

Answer (score 2):

[Apparently](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/three-ways-to-prevent-spotlight-from-indexing-items-on-your-mac/) adding '.noindex' to a parent folder name will prevent Spotlight from indexing.

NB: I haven't personally verified.