# Where does Spotlight keeps the excluded folders

Tags: finder, spotlight, plist

Does Spotlight keeps the privacy excluded folders in some special configuration file ?

Those folder are configured under 
**system preferences -> spotlight -> privacy**

I believe it should be somewhere under `/Library/Preferences/` ..
This data is persistent so it must be kept in file, but which one, perhaps it's not purely textual file (xml plist format) but binary one ?

EDIT: I've found out that the file which keeps the file reside in 
`/.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist` in the `Exclusions` array :

```
    <key>Exclusions</key>
    <array>
    ...
    ..
    .
    </array>
```

However, if I add new exclusion to the list, it doesn't appear on the UI.

thanks

Comment: With macOS System Integrity Protection these files aren't writable any longer.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87090/how-to-programatically-add-folder-to-spotlight-do-not-index