# How to stop AppleScript application content files from appearing in "Recents" folders?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript

I'm a big fan of AppleScript and am currently utilising it for a range of different tasks on my computer. However, one thing I have noticed is that after I have created an Application in AppleScript, many of the content files including the `main.scpt` and the `applet.icns` files begin appearing in my "Recents" folder in Finder. This can be rather annoying as it quickly clogs up my recents folder especially if I have been working on a number of different apps.

My question is: how do I make sure that only the application itself can be viewed in the recents folder and not some of its content files as well. If so, how would I do this? Is it possible to do when creating the application itself?

Comment: The worst possible solution but may work. Set up a Folder Action that changes the permissions of the contents to write only.

Comment: @JBis Thank you for the suggestion! However, I'm afraid that whilst this would probably work, I was hoping that maybe there could be something done the the application itself i.e. without requiring the execution of another command outside of the application itself. Thanks once again.

Comment: You need like a Spotlight Exception wild card;

Comment: May have slightly better solution. What directory do you save your AppleScripts to usually?

Comment: @JBis My AppleScripts are stored in a subdirectory in my Documents folder. What would your suggestion be?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/91759/263848 with a folder action AppleScript

Answer (score 1):

The following answer will add a `.metadata_never_index` file inside the Application folder. [This will prevent indexing by Spotlight of the folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87090/how-to-programatically-add-folder-to-spotlight-do-not-index?noredirect=1&lq=1) hopefully preventing it from appearing in Recents.

---

Here's the script. Save it to `/Library/Scripts/Folder Actions Scripts/`:

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    --  Called after items have been added to a folder
    --
    --  theFolder is a reference to the modified folder
    --  theNewItems is a list of references to the items added to the folder 
    repeat with myItem in theNewItems
        tell application "Finder"
            if myItem's name extension is "app" then -- make sure its an app
                set myPath to the POSIX path of myItem
                do shell script "touch " & quoted form of (myPath & ".metadata_never_index")
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat

end adding folder items to
```

1. Navigate to the folder where you save your Apple Scripts
2. Right click on that folder and select `Services>Folder Actions Setup`

[image][image]

3. Select the script that saved and click `Attach`
4. Make sure `Enable Folder Actions` is checked in the upper left
5. Test.
6. Celebrate!

Comment: Thank you for you excellent answer! Whilst is isn't necessarily what I had in mind (i.e. doing something to the app itself to prevent this in the first place) it definitely is a perfectly acceptable solution for the overall. Thanks!